# Why is my array not displayed in TableForm?

Tags: output-formatting, syntax

Why is the array produced by the following not displayed in `TableForm`?

```
NumberForm[Table[Sum[(-1)^n 1/n!, {n, 0, i}], {i, 10}] // N, 12] // TableForm
```

> `{0., 0.5, 0.333333333333, 0.375, 0.366666666667, 0.368055555556, 0.367857142857, 0.367881944444, 0.367879188713, 0.367879464286}`

What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: `TableForm` works on `List`s; you want to use it on something with a head `NumberForm`. Try `NumberForm[TableForm@Table[Sum[(-1)^n 1/n!, {n, 0, i}], {i, 10}] // N, 12]`.

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25463/5467)

Comment: Also related: [(6197)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6197/121), [(23006)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23006/121), [(47330)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47330/121)